# tf::waitForTransform() does not wait for transform

Tags: rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

First I recorded a rosbag with "-a" , so that clock and tf's are included.

Then, I playback the rosbag with the "--clock" option.
I asses that tf is ok and all links exist with tf_monitor.

In parallel (in the same launch file) I launch a node X that uses a TransformListener.
In that node X, before any transformation, I would like to wait for transforms, just in case rosbag recording added some delay on weaking up tf. So, I put that :

`tfListener.waitForTransform("base_link", myFrameName, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0),ros::Duration(0.1));`

And the execution breaks after 3 seconds aprox, so it does not wait for 10 seconds.

However, If I put (please note I change polling rate but timeout remains the same)

`tfListener.waitForTransform("base_link", myFrameName, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0),ros::Duration(1.0));`

then the execution waits correctly up to tf is available.

Can anyone comment or answer this issue ?

Thank you very much !

best regards,

andreu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12358/tf::waitfortransform()-does-not-wait-for-transform-.../) by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please file a ticket for this, and attach a bag file and sample code to reproduce.  https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/trac/newticket

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1